# How to retrieve value from PFUser as String?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, ios8

I am querying my user base for only users who are ranked as `Honor` using the following code:

```
var HQuery = PFUser.query()
        HQuery!.whereKey("rank", equalTo:"H")
        var Honor = HQuery!.findObjects()
        let Name=Honor["Username"] as String //Error Here

        println(Honor)
```

The console prints out the following:

```
Optional([<PFUser: 0x7fe610e26610, objectId: TFRpx5r7ne, localId: (null)> {
    class = H;
    email = "Raul@moor.com";
    phone = 8002248472;
    username = Raul;
}])
```

**The Problem Is** that I can't get the username, `Raul`, out as just a String using the code above. I get the error message where I specified `Error Here` which says: `Cannot subscript a value of type '[AnyObject]?' with an index of type 'String`.

How can I fix this error, and just get the username out as a String?

Answer (score 0):

Here, `honor` is an array of objects,

```
for obj : AnyObject in honor! {
   let name = obj["Username"] as! String
    println(name)
}
```

Try like this.

Comment: Thankyou again. However it does not work, I get the error: `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional`. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that "Username" key  is having a value?

Comment: Yes I am sure because with the other method it was printing.

Comment: It should work.. If possible make sure again it has some value.. I tried same  ,its working for me. If there is no value, I will get the same error like yours or else it works perfectly.

Comment: There is no error at runtime, but once you start using the app it crashes when the view loads